# Mongodb disc space

Tags: mongodb

We a one collection in which every document have average 16 KB size, and document count is 30,000, that's mean total space should be

```
(30,000 * 16) / 1024 * 2024 = 1.71 GB
```

but we found size of collection in collection stats is `28.6 GB`, its horrible. Can anybody tell how can this possible, I have checked ea liar when we have only 736 documents in this doc that time it was consuming 18.5 MB only. i this collection we are storing only numeric data not any text or large string.

Is Mongo db extra space for collection or anything?

Here is stats info.

```
> db.MyCollection.stats()
{
        "ns" : "DB.MyCollection",
        "count" : 31228,
        "size" : 30593236376,
        "avgObjSize" : 979673.254002818,
        "storageSize" : 31878659904,
        "numExtents" : 33,
        "nindexes" : 1,
        "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "systemFlags" : 1,
        "userFlags" : 0,
        "totalIndexSize" : 923888,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 923888
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

**Edit**

This is stats I have captured earlier (when record count was 736)

```
> db.MyCollection.stats()
{
        "ns" : "DB.MyCollection",
        "count" : 736,
        "size" : 18985944,
        "avgObjSize" : 25796.119565217392,
        "storageSize" : 23035904,
        "numExtents" : 4,
        "nindexes" : 1,
        "lastExtentSize" : 11681792,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "systemFlags" : 1,
        "userFlags" : 0,
        "totalIndexSize" : 32704,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 32704
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

And I am using Insertion only not updating but querying very frequently.

Some information may help to identify situation :

- Schema of collection is deep tree structure (7 level)
- Using Windows server for mongodb (but got same issue on MongoLab (Amazon hosted) instance also)
- Moved collection to another db (on another server) also using only insertion statements but BulkInsertion and consumed same size there also.

Sample Data : I have renamed fields name

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("50ff7614c9145359648cc017"),
   "gtrtt":2,
   "XYZ":2,
   "Namecount":2,
   "ABC":0,
   "123":0,
   "IDD":793,
   "date":   ISODate("2012-04-22T00:00:00   Z"),
   "network":[
      {
         "gtrtt":2,
         "XYZ":2,
         "Namecount":2,
         "ABC":0,
         "123":0,
         "type":"facebook",
         "safasfasf":[
            {
               "gtrtt":2,
               "XYZ":2,
               "Namecount":2,
               "ABC":0,
               "123":0,
               "type":0,
               "sassasas":[
                  {
                     "gtrtt":2,
                     "XYZ":2,
                     "Namecount":2,
                     "ABC":0,
                     "123":0,
                     "type":2,
                     "asfasffasfsafas":[
                        {
                           "gtrtt":2,
                           "XYZ":2,
                           "Namecount":2,
                           "ABC":0,
                           "123":0,
                           "type":5,
                           "435435345":[
                              {
                                 "gtrtt":2,
                                 "XYZ":2,
                                 "Namecount":2,
                                 "ABC":0,
                                 "123":0,
                                 "type":"Egypt",
                                 "34534534435345":[
                                    {
                                       "gtrtt":1,
                                       "XYZ":1,
                                       "Namecount":1,
                                       "ABC":0,
                                       "123":0,
                                       "type":"Cairo"
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "gtrtt":1,
                                       "XYZ":1,
                                       "Namecount":1,
                                       "ABC":0,
                                       "123":0,
                                       "type":null
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "OS":[
      {
         "gtrtt":1,
         "XYZ":1,
         "Namecount":1,
         "ABC":0,
         "123":0,
         "type":"Windows7"
      },
      {
         "gtrtt":1,
         "XYZ":1,
         "Namecount":1,
         "ABC":0,
         "123":0,
         "type":"WindowsXP"
      }
   ],
   "Browser":[
      {
         "gtrtt":1,
         "XYZ":1,
         "Namecount":1,
         "ABC":0,
         "123":0,
         "type":"IE"
      },
      {
         "gtrtt":1,
         "XYZ":1,
         "Namecount":1,
         "ABC":0,
         "123":0,
         "type":"Firefox"
      }
   ],
   "Device":[
      {
         "gtrtt":2,
         "XYZ":2,
         "Namecount":2,
         "ABC":0,
         "123":0,
         "type":"PC"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to make some assumptions here however, form an educated guess, I would say they are true.

All measurements you show there are in bytes.

Your average object size (document) is actually 0.9 meg not 16KB.

So you are actually using: 28.4922 GB about (you have 31228 objects in that collection). That is what MongoDB says anyway.

You are actually using 29.6893 GB of storage.

This actually kind of makes sense due to pre-allocation of future extents (I think in this case it will pre-alloc a new 2GB file here) and possible fragmentation, however your fragmentation is not very high, maybe a couple of MBs so I would not say that is your problem but you could run a compact on that collection regardless to remove that if it causes a problem.

I would also say your padding factor is probably sitting at about `1` or just a bit over considering the amount of fragmentation so this is not too much of a problem, it will allocate just larger than the object size here.

Indexes are a separate namespace so they shouldn't be effecting your collections namespace extents too much, if at all.

I think your main problem is that you have misread and misunderstood the output and true size of your dataset.

#### Edit

If you frequently updating (not inserting into) this collection that could explain the avgObjSize and your assumption in which case a compact should bring the collection back down to tameable size.

Comment: I am not using any update operation + I have run compact command but not changed anything.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya And you are inserting relatively the same strucutre each time? No sort of extra levels being dynamically created and all that? Can you show us one of these docs?

Comment: not same structure, I am using tree structure for it. number of child may vary in all documents.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya Hmm I think you might have a run away loop that is making a huge tree structure somewhere in your code. Maybe something about 736 docs is the clue? I do think you will find the solution in your code possibly.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya One way you can test this is to iterate all 31k of your rows, BSON encoding the returned document in either the js console or your application and testing it's length to see how big your largest document is, see if some are really going that high

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya I'll test it later when I got a bit of time :) but it seems that this should not be too bad on size so you might only get a real answer by finding what really is your biggest doc (form my previous comment).

Comment: If compact didn't do the trick your documents will be that big. Or at least some are very big. Take a look here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/wVMLQqRDL70/I3gn1gpuARkJ this should give you a glimpse on how to work on only those documents bigger than a given size. Maybe this helps to identify the problem.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya Yea I couldn't see many problems here, I would try the script that philnate posted in the google group and see what you get out of it

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account that indexes increase the collection size as well. Additionally mongodb has some paddingfactor which is applied to documents. This allows that documents can increase in size, without the need to move the document always even if it's just one byte more. The padding factor is quite unstable and changes a lot. So with the paddingfactor your collection increases as well. See [stats()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/collection-statistics/)

From your output:

Indexes seem to be no problem, just your _id index. Padding factor seems to be no problem either, but this hasn't to say anything as this is only the actual padding factor applied to new writes. But what looks problematic is that mongodb reports your avgObjSize with roughly 956kB rather than your suspected 16kB. So you either look into the wrong collection or have something different saved than you expect you're saving (not sure where your 16kB is coming from).

What you can do is running compact to [compact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/) the collection and check afterwards what space was allocated due to the padding factor.